# character "<" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data PHP use

Tags: php, xhtml

Hi there I am trying to make an xhtml 1.1 website which requires a form to carry out a PHP_SELF  operation in the form action. To do this requires me to use the opening tag of php

```
<?php
```

However when I check the validation on the W3 website the response I get is :

> character "`<`" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data

I have tried the solution which the validator tells me which is to swap the `<` infront of the php for `&lt;` but when I do this the php code wont work properly. Does anyone know of a solution to this.

Comment: If you're submitting to PHP_SELF, I think you can remove the 'action' completely

Comment: I'd stay away from XHTML. It's a technological cul-de-sac and never enjoyed good support from browsers (unless you pretended it was HTML, in which case - what's the point?).

Comment: adjust yourself rather blaming XHTML. change in php.ini from short_open_tag = On to short_open_tag = Off

Comment: @www.sblog.in — Short tags are not the problem. XHTML is not the problem. The problem is that you can't use a markup validator to validate PHP source code.

Comment: I'd shy away from HTML that isn't XHTML. HTML alone is an unstructured mess.

Comment: @www.sblog.in I have no idea where tou got short_open_tag from. He's not even using a short tag.

Comment: @YTowOnt9 — HTML allows (in very clearly defined circumstances) quotes around attribute values, attribute values, and tags to be omitted. That doesn't make it unstructured. The structure is very clearly defined. HTML has, expressed in its DTD, more rigorous rules about where elements are allowed than XHTML. XHTML makes validation less useful. It also requires that you jump through the HTML Compatibility Guidelines if you want to pretend it is HTML (which you will).

Comment: @Quentin I am okay with omitting tags such as `tbody`, but not omitting half a tag. The DOM is a tree and a document for serializing the DOM should clearly show where each subtree starts and ends. There shouldn't be unclosed `p`, `li`, or `br` tags. There aren't any in the DOM. It just makes the HTML appear unstructured,  which makes it harder for people to learn it. It doesn't help that browser's try to parse invalid HTML instead of displaying an error page.

Answer (score 2):

Run the PHP. Validate the (X)HTML you get out of it.

Don't try to validate the PHP source code.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer abit please as im new to both php and xhtml. I am currently uploading the file to the w3 validator as im running it on a local host ( sorry should have mentioned that in my original question I imagine). Do you mean submit the form after I have entered the data and then check it on the w3 validator?

Comment: When you request the URL from your server, the PHP will be executed and the HTML will be sent to the browser. You'll (presumably) get a *different* HTML document when you submit the form. Either way, you need to validate the HTML you get from your web server and not the source code of the PHP program that you run to get the HTML.

Comment: Ah I think I understand now thank you. Its a development project which will eventually require me to submit screenshots and wont have a proper live, public server running which means that the url is a localhost url which the w3 validator wont allow. I imagine the only way then to validate it correctly is to remove the php scripts in the form and if it validates then paste the scripts back in place.

Comment: Install a local copy of the validator.

Comment: Or view your page in a browser and then save the output to a file and validate that.